# Как в Android Studio запустить JUnit тест?

Tags: android-studio, junit

В принципе весь вопрос в заголовке. У меня имеется 2 директории в папке java, одна из них для тестов, в Idea заданы параметры, указывающие в какой директории тесты, и она подсвечивается зелёным фоном. Там есть уже стандартный тест от Google на само Application, но я создал свои тесты, но как их запустить я понятия не имею, в интернете однозначного ответа не нашёл, лишь только инфу, как подключить JUnit в зависимости в gradle. В Eclipse всё куда проще. Как быть мне?

**Добавлено:**
Нашёл [доки от гугл](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support), но кидает ошибку при компиляции:

Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyLineViewExample'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0.
>        Required by:
>            :MyLineViewExample:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.0/gradle-1.3.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.0/gradle-1.3.0.pom'.
>   Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) есть все ответы. Сразу надо было поискать получше